# Windows Server Appfabric provider for asp.net output caching

Tags: asp.net, appfabric

Does asp.net output cache provider exist for Windows Server AppFabric 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But because output caching is pluggable in ASP.NET 4.0 (using the provider model), you can write your own.

To create a new output cache provider, you'll need to inherit from `System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheProvider`, you'll need to reference `System.Web` and `System.Configuration`.

Then it's largely a case of overriding the four methods from the base provider, Add, Get, Remove and Set.

As your site is probably going to getting quite a few hits, you'll definitely want to use a Singleton for the DataCacheFactory, this code uses [Jon Skeet's singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) (assuming I've understood it correctly).

```
using System;
using System.Web.Caching;
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;

namespace AppFabricOutputCache
{
public sealed class AppFabricOutputCacheProvider : OutputCacheProvider
{
    private static readonly AppFabricOutputCacheProvider instance = new AppFabricOutputCacheProvider();
    private DataCacheFactory factory;
    private DataCache cache;

    static AppFabricOutputCacheProvider()
    { }

    private AppFabricOutputCacheProvider()
    {
        // Constructor - new up the factory and get a reference to the cache based 
        // on a setting in web.config
        factory = new DataCacheFactory();
        cache = factory.GetCache(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutputCacheName"]);
    }

    public static AppFabricOutputCacheProvider Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    public override object Add(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry)
    {
        // Add an object into the cache. 
        // Slight disparity here in that we're passed an absolute expiry but AppFabric wants
        // a TimeSpan. Subtract Now from the expiry we get passed to create the TimeSpan
        cache.Add(key, entry, utcExpiry - DateTime.UtcNow);
    }

    public override object Get(string key)
    {
        return cache.Get(key);
    }

    public override void Remove(string key)
    {
        cache.Remove(key);
    }

    public override void Set(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry)
    {
        // Set here means 'add it if it doesn't exist, update it if it does'
        // We can do this by using the AppFabric Put method
        cache.Put(key, entry, utcExpiry - DateTime.UtcNow);
    }
}
}
```

Once you've got this written, you need to configure your application to use it in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
        <outputCache defaultProvider="AppFabricOutputCache">
            <providers>
                <add name="AppFabricOutputCache" type="AppFabricOutputCache, AppFabricOutputCacheProvider" />
            </providers>
        </outputCache>
     </caching>
</system.web>
```

[MSDN: OutputCacheProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.outputcacheprovider.aspx)
[ScottGu's blog on creating OutputCacheProviders](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/27/extensible-output-caching-with-asp-net-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)